# Dynamically Pruning a Table

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a table which is undergoing regular schema changes. It has around 80 columns currently. Some columns are read only.

To refresh our dev environment, we copy the prod DB, prune it and anonymize it. I have a procedure that is run after the prod DB is copied to zap anything older than 6 months. It does this using this:

```
DECLARE @theBeginning DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE());

SELECT Id,
       Date,
       ColA,
       ColB,
       ColC,
       ..etc
INTO #temp
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE Date > @theBeginning;

DECLARE @movedCount INT = 0;
SELECT @movedCount = COUNT(1)
FROM #temp;

PRINT @movedCount

IF (@movedCount > 0)
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE [MyTable];
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]
    (
       Date,
       ColA,
       ColB,
       ColC,
       ... etc
    )
    SELECT Date,
       ColA,
       ColB,
       ColC,
       ..etc
    FROM #temp;
```

This is clunky, since it needs constant maintenance to keep the column list up to date.

We can't just do a `DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Date < @theBeginning` since it takes forever. The select, truncate and insert is around 10x quicker.

Is it possible to do this dynamically, so we achieve the same result without the constant manual tweaking of the list of columns?

Comment: You should take a look here: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281). Specifically the parts about updating your question to add details that will help you get an acceptable answer. If a bunch of additional details come out in comments, it will be more difficult to follow the dialog..

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this for all the columns in the table, then you can use "*" in both SELECT lists, and omit the column list from the INSERT portion of the statement.  If the Id column is an identity, you will need to set identity inserts to on for that table.

```
DECLARE @theBeginning DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE());

SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE Date > @theBeginning;

DECLARE @movedCount INT = 0;
SELECT @movedCount = COUNT(1)
FROM #temp;

PRINT @movedCount

IF (@movedCount > 0)
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE [MyTable];

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]
    SELECT *
    FROM #temp;

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] OFF;
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that some columns are read only.

Comment: @Echilon Do you mean computed columns?  There's nothing called read only columns in SQL Server that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table which is undergoing regular schema changes.

That is a big red flag. Do not do it. Never-never-never. You condemn yourself to constantly keep and modify list of columns in procedures, views, and statements which use this table. If you are sure that the object, you describe in this table, requires different number of columns at different times - consider redesigning to [EAV data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Many problems will disappear.

If you must do it this way - you can do a select from a virtual table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

You can build a command line using such query in any external client. And even do it within a stored procedure, with a dynamic execution [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
But this is a very unmaintainable and prone to errors approach.